# prove that there is a group representation of $\Bbb Z$ which is not totally decomposable over $\Bbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

prove that there is a group representation of $\Bbb Z$ which is not totally decomposable over $\Bbb C$

what I tried -

let $\mu: \Bbb Z \to GL_{2*2} \Bbb (C)$

$$\mu(x)(v) =  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & x \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

and then showed invariant field

$L =  \begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

that does not have an invariant complement.

I have used this way to prove that there is a group representation of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ that is not decomposable over a field $\Bbb F_p$
So I think i might have a mistake somewhere and that it is not the solution in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so your question is essentially whether there is some mistake on your above mentioned method ?

Comment: my question is how to solve (or approach) this question if my answer is wrong . and why it is wrong. please

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: in your answer, do you consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a $2d$ real space, so $a,b$ are real ?

Comment: yes . but Im not sure if it is ok to do that . because it is over $\Bbb C$

Comment: and i think it is wrong because that is exactly what I used for showing that $ Z/p\Bbb Z$  is not decomposable over a field $\Bbb F_p$   and because I'm confused from the meaning of decomposable over C

Comment: the term "decomposable over $\mathbb{C}$" seems a bit confusing to me.  I guess that you mean $\mathbb{C}$ is the carrier space and it is a real $2d$ space. If this is the case, then $\mu$ should be $\mu: \mathbb{Z} \to GL_{2,2} (\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show that the $1d$ subspace $L$ of $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, generated by $\begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, does not have an invariant complement:

Let $\begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, with $\frac{b}{a}=\textrm{const}\neq 0$ be a vector,  generating an $1d$ invariant subspace of $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a complement of $L$ (note that a necessary condition for being a complement is $b\neq 0$). Thus for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$\mu(x)\begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & x \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
       \begin{pmatrix}
        a  \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a+bx \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
But $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{b}{a+bx}$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, implies $b=0$, leading to the conclusion that no complement of $L$ is invariant under $\mu$.

Thus, $\mu:\mathbb{Z} \to GL_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is an indecomposable representation of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ on the $2d$ real vector space $\mathbb{C}$.